# setting javascript value from backend code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, javascript-framework

I would like to know how I can set a javascript value from my backend code. 
I have this line of JS code:

```
 gts.push([ 'google_base_offer_id', 'ITEM_PRODUCT_SEARCH_ID']);
```

What I am trying at this moment is:

```
gts.push(['google_base_offer_id', document.getElementById("hidden").value]);
```

I have hidden value set in the markup:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" />
```

and in the backend code, OnPreRender event, I am doing this:

hidden.Value = product.ProductId.ToString();

The value gets set properly but when I am viewing source in the browser the value is not populated. 
Am I doing something wrong, is it possible to populate the value like that?
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: That ID will change, you need to set the ClientId.

Comment: when you view source, is the ID of the hidden field still "hidden"? asp.net sometimes changes the ID of asp elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it like:

```
gts.push(['google_base_offer_id', document.getElementById('<%= hidden.ClientID %>').value]);
```

Comment: Any encoding issues here, as this is JavaScript embedded within HTML...  Shouldn't it be `<%= some_asp_json_encode_function(hidden.ClientID %>` ?

Comment: @Danite nothing happens I am getting this: http://gyazo.com/a7be6c637f975a1f1a6fd7794175bc95

Comment: So, you got the ID of the hidden field. You just have to use the getElementById... I update my answer.

Comment: Looks good to me. When you load the page, the script is going to run and the value will be used in gts.push. Are you even checking if gts has the correct values *after* the push method call?

Comment: @Dante when I am doing alert(ProductId) I can see the value I need, and now I am doing like this: http://gyazo.com/ed288479fe46803ce04e87ff2784bc3b, there are no errors in the code, but when I am going view source I am seeing this:http://gyazo.com/759a6c29cabdb3e9190e63b087f28f64 I expected to see the value of the productID instead of the productID var. Its strange because with the alert command the value is printed out correctly, but with view source, productID is the one which I am seeing.

Comment: Of course, it's JavaScript. JavaScript runs in the client, not in the server. <%= hidden.ClientID %> is processed server side and is sent to the browser as the actual value stored in the hidden field, but javascript code runs in the browser, so you'll see your ProductId variable, or document.getElementById. I recommend you read more about client vs server side code.

Comment: @Dante so the way the code looks at this moment, you think Google robots will be able to get the proper value for the productID? Thanks

Comment: I think you have a lot more to be concerned, than Google robots. Again, read a bit more about client side code (JavaScript), server side code, it has nothing to do with Google robots. The way your design your page, that has all to do with SEO...

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this way:

If you are using a ScriptManager in your page, then in the code behind you could register the javascript value in a hidden field

```
ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField(this, "hiddenKey", "hiddenValue");
```

Then in aspx page you could use

```
gts.push(['google_base_offer_id', document.getElementById("hiddenKey").value]);
```